# How many desktop configurations when accessing PC remotely?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm accessing a specific PC from several other computers (say, a work computer from a home desktop and also from a laptop).

each of these computers have a different screen resolution and aspect ratio so each would have slightly differtnt desktop configuration (in terms of background pictures abd icon placement).

My question is: Is there a limit on ow many different desktop cofiguration can one windows PC remember? When does a new remote connection overwrites previous desktop setups?

Comment: What has your research shown? You certainly have connected to this machine using two different clients? Are you logging into the same user? A single user on a machine typically would have the same desktop.  The resolution of the Remote Desktop, would be set by the RDC, so would be stored on the client not the machine being accessed. Your real question is hard to decipher

Comment: My "research" is that the original non-remote desktop and one remote connection work without disrupting each other. The question is how many additional remote connections (with different screen resolutions and aspect ratios) can be connected to the one computer remotely, without them disrupting eachother.

Comment: What do you mean by "disrupting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer that remembers the screen size etc. are the remote computers, or the app that you are using to connect and it forces specific size.

Without app name it is hard to tell how many computers can be remembered. Best solution currently is for example TeamViewer which supports many systems and is well written.

EDIT:

So with mstsc there is no limit for remembering the sessions, you are limited only by disk space for that (.RDP files).

Comment: The question is about the standard windows-10 "remote desktop connection".

Comment: @BoTz see edit.

Comment: Do you mean there is no theoretical limit to the different configurations, and that each combination of resolution and aspect ratio would get it's separate .RDP configuration file?

Comment: @BoTz yes, this is possible this way. Limit is disk space.

Comment: OK, great. This answers my question. Thanks!